# Managing Multi-Project Branches in Git

Tags: git, maven, structure, git-flow

Are there tools to achieve the following abstract operations in a Maven project/SCM scenario?

- Given an application project, create branches for the application and all the snapshot libraries that it uses, transitively; these branches should be manageable as one logical branch (see next)
- Given the logical branch of an application project, release it (by running Maven release); this means releasing multiple branches, one per library

Background (original):

As you know, Git recommends using the repository-per-project structuring paradigm. At the same time, any serious project, in our case Maven-based, is attached to several in-house libraries. During any sprint, both the project and the libraries that it is attached to are modified. In a Git world, this means that modifications will exist across several Git repositories.

If we wanted to branch out the work in the sprint, perhaps because we use Gitflow, which invites that we create a release branch at the end of our sprint, how would we do it in a logical manner across all the libraries involved in the sprint, instead of manually branching each library?

A Maven-aware tool (one that can introspect the POMs to figure out the transitive snapshot dependency list) will be even better.

Can I create a logical relationship between my multiple physical branches (one per project) that represent my one logical branch?

Does Git, or some Git tool, support logical branches?

I'm hoping you're not going to say submodules. What I'm looking for here is to abstract out the details of the VCS, not to become a Git guru. Also, I'm looking to do things in one operation where possible, as having to individually branch each library is error prone and easily forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) server.

It can build each maven module as a separate project and then automatically rebuild any other projects that has a snapshot dependency relationship.

## Update

The GIT plugin for Jenkins has a feature for managing the automatic merging of development feature branches into a "master" or "integration" branch. See the documentation:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures

Another option is to control feature development using a code review tool like [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).
Again it's Gerrit that controls changes integrated onto the shared code stream and Gerrit can be integrated with Jenkins to ensuring all submitted change-sets pass the code tests.

Finally releases are cut using the [M2 Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin), which is a wrapper around the standard release plugin. (Means you'll always have two types of build in Jenkins. Automated builds triggered by code commits and release builds explicitly triggered via the UI).

Comment: Mark, what I need is to create branches in SCM by clicking a button to prepare for a release. Ideally, the POM structure would be inspected and the libraries on a snapshot version identified. Those specific libraries would be branched (probably using the same branch name in their respective repositories). When the branch is created, trunk snapshots would be updated. The branches would be managed as one. That is, if I choose to merge the branch by name into another branch, all the libraries would be merged. `maven:branch` could be used as a subroutine. This would ideally be an atomic operation.

Comment: These guys seem to have just said "no" to the repository-per-project paradigm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084625/project-organization-using-maven-git?rq=1

Comment: @MihaiDanila I suppose the answer depends on whether the libraries will all be released together, in which case you'd setup a multi-module build with parent and child modules, all in the same repo (because it's really one project). The M2 Release plugin in Jenkins leverages the standard Maven release plugin and will take care of revision numbers and all that other good stuff.

Comment: You're suggesting that the single-repository pattern might be the way to go if the libraries evolve in lockstep with the application. That is not the case today. The libraries are used by applications owned by different teams. I don't think it makes sense to have a single repository for all these applications, especially since different teams own them. I don't know where that leaves us.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Exactly. If each library has a separate release life-cycle then they must have their own repo (release tagging). I would suggest that in development, you have dependencies on the snapshot revisions of you collaborating projects. The beauty of this is that Jenkins will automatically rebuild your project whenever one of your dependencies is built (provided they're sharing Jenkins). Haven't used the release plugin in a while, but I seem to remember it edits the POM file removing any snapshot dependencies. This effectively pins your release against stable versions of your dependencies

Comment: The release plugin will by default require us to release any snapshot libraries recursively, so that that we can "freeze" their code and point to the version thus obtained. This brings us back to the question at hand, which is branching for a release. How do I manage the branch across several repos as one? Create as one, merge as one, delete as one. And the repos that need to be branched for each branch may be different (because different libraries are changed for each release). Any tools for that?

Comment: @MihaiDanila I've updated my answer with details on how feature branching can be handled. I would suggest solving the problem on a repository by repository basis, after all each each is effectively a separate project with it's own release life-cycle. BTW if you're attempting to support multiple maintenance branches....Try and avoid it... Few open source projects support anything other than the latest version. It's a lot cheaper :-)

Comment: Like it often does, the answer has alerted me to some of my less valuable assumptions. What are the lifecycles of the libraries relative to the lifecycle of the project? Are they divorced? If so, keep them separate. Are they entangled (closer to a Maven multi-module project)? If so, perhaps they should be in the same repository after all. My case seems to be a mix of the two: libraries have their own lifecycle, but they are often released in lockstep with my application. I've accepted your answer because it alerted me to this complication. Nonetheless, I would like better tooling around this.

Comment: Hey @MihaiDanila, we've encountered exactly the complexity you're describing- could you post and detail your solution somewhere?  in our case we decided that libraries and applications would each be managed in its own git repo, and would always be versioned 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in their master branch, and dependent on the same, thus always using the latest and greatest. Once an application reaches feature-freeze, we wrote a create-branch.sh tool, which creates a branch with the same name for the app and for each lib, and changes their version to the same name as the branch with a SNAPSHOT suffix.

Comment: Hey ihadanny, in the end we didn't find any tools, so we started writing an in-house tool that can use `mvn` as a subroutine to ask various questions of the POM. The tool can then add to a branch, and later it will be able to release all the pieces in a branch, recursively. It's all `bash` and it is able thus far to add items from trunk or from tag into a given named branch. We follow a model whereby it is the trunk version that gets increased when branching, not the branch version. This enables our trunk to be the location for the current version.

Comment: It also simplifies the question "what should the next version be" when branching. In effect, the version in trunk is like a sequence number.

Comment: @ihadanny: I no longer have access to that codebase, but I reached out to a friend who does, and he kindly provided the relevant details. (The code is not competitive advantage or anything like it - it's just basic plumbing available on the web.) Where would you like me to provide this? Stackoverflow question? E-mail?

Comment: @MihaiDanila - wow, thanks! can you publish the code in some github and post the link here (as an answer or comment)?

Comment: I don't have a Github account that I know of, but perhaps you can shoot me an e-mail that I can reply to? viridium@gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Look what I found looking for something else about Gitflow:
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

It doesn't work with Maven, so it doesn't fit my needs, but maybe it helps you.